# How to solve Page Caching bbin Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, caching, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

The first page in Windows Phone is always cached, that means when you run the app then press back button to close the app then reopen the app from the phone or the simulator (not from visual studio) the page events such as the constructor, NavigationHelper_LoadState, and OnNavigatedTo are not called, even I disabled page cashing by

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Disabled;
```

and in App.xaml.cs

```
rootFrame.CacheSize = 0;
```

But still cached.

How can I solve this problem because I need to get data from a server and show it in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you load data in OnNavigatedTo? If you need to load data in constructor you can also try to remove page from navigation stack.